# Change UITableViewCell background color when it's in reordering edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Reorder UITableViewCell inside UITableViewCell with changing background color of current reorder cell, in UITableView edit mode.

Code gist - https://gist.github.com/filsv/c788a533fa233d8bb30126ccf00ab735

Comment: Please provide more detail and it will be better write the code here you are using.

Comment: Yes, no problem, few sec.